# Clear cache with all time range using selenium Java without using additional libraries

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Clear cache with all time range using selenium Java without using additional libraries

```
driver.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData");
WebElement e= driver.findElement(By.xpath (//settings-ui"));
e.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);//Moves selection from cancel to Clear data button
e.sendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

This code is currently implemented just want to add a drop down selection to All time rage instead of default last one hour

Many ways I tried including multiple Tabs and some Iwebdriver shadow root code I found from websites but Iwebdriver is not getting detected

Also tried deleteallcookies statement

Comment: the select list you are trying to interact is within the shadow-dom.

Comment: Yes @Rajagopalan, I am not that much experienced and I am finding it hard to understand  how to interact with shadow dom elements

Comment: that second e.sendKeys() method will happen on your "e" element, too.  (so it's not going to be at Clear data button)  Remember that you are using the webelement's sendKeys method.  That method first puts focus in that element (if it's an input), and then sends the keys to it.  On top of that, you can't send keys to a button.  Btw, if you want to clear the cache, you can just quit, and re-launch the driver.  By default it will begin with a new, temporary, profile.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a new `ChromeDriver` instance, the browser cache is already cleared so you shouldn't need to clear cache at the start of a script. If you are trying to clear cache in the middle of running a script, you can use

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```